# How to access a web page INPUT element using selenium python

Tags: selenium, python

Below is my website content

```
<input type="text" title="Query for bugs (&quot;Go box&quot;) [Alt-K]"
       name="Go" id="GoText" size="23"
       onkeypress="GoBoxKeypress(event)" onblur="GoBoxBlur(event)" 
       onfocus="GoBoxFocus(event)" onclick="GoBoxKeypress(null)" 
       class="filter" accesskey="k" value="">
```

i wanted to access the text field 
i have tried below things

```
abc=driver.find_element_by_id('GoText')
a=driver.find_element_by_name('go')
```

but still I am not able to access the element

Comment: Are you getting an error? Which one?

Comment: Please show the error(s) and also how you set up `driver`

Answer (score 1):

The selectors seem ok.
There may be something wrong in your setup.
Please show how `driver` is being defined and how you are pointing at the page in question.

For example please show lines similar to:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.yoursite.org")
```

Are you getting `NoSuchElementException` ?

What if you try `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input')` do you get anything or an error?

See also http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using def, try this:

```
def test_1(self):
    abc=self.driver.find_element_by_id('GoText')
```

Comment: care to explain what it will do?

Comment: share your full code to sort out the problem.